# Hard coded path in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am calling .exe file from .net core web application. I used hard coded path to call .exe but I was wondering if there is a better way to configure this path so even if i run it on a different system it will call the same file.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Runcase(List<string> products, string runnumber, string button)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var process = new Process();
                    process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Repos\ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\");
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Repos\ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\", "ConsoleApp.exe");
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Join(",", products) + " " + runnumber + " " + button;
                    var p = process.Start();
                    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                    if (p == null)
                    {
                        return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        process.WaitForExit();
                        process.Close();
                        return View();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: _I was wondering if there is a better way to configure path so even if i run it on a different system it will call the same file_ - can you explain what this means, and how it will work in practice?

Comment: Put the file path in a config file.

Comment: @Han,Should I put the Same path?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I have added file path in my code. Should I make changes or use the same?

Comment: As an alternative, you can look for a file with a specific name in the same directory as the executable, if you're interested in that solution I can post an answer.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia, That would be great if you can post an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but you can find the directory where the executable is running using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` then just append a hard-coded file name at the end.

eg:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ConsoleApp.exe");
```

Comment: If I am calling .exe file from controller, can I use the same approach you mentioned ?I have console app and web app in different project.

Comment: @Neu - note that for user apps (console/winforms/WPF/...) it is frequently bad idea to rely on current directory as often those programs launched from different directory than they are located. Depending on your needs there are likely better duplicates than this suggestion - i.e. "C# current application directory" may be a search term. There is no guarantees for current directory for web site once at all.